# NetBeans IDE autocomplete 'contains'

Tags: java, netbeans

Does anybody know if there is a way to get NetBeans code autocomplete to filter by 'contains' rather than 'starts with'.

E.g.  MyClass has getBlaBla(), setBlaBla() and someOtherBlaBla()

I want to be able to say MyClass.BlaBla and for the code completion to suggest all three of the method names above.  Would be really useful for when you dont quite remember what the method name was but know it contains that word.

Comment: Note: The coding convention for Java is to start method names with a small letter.

Comment: Nice one. I sense a feature request in the making.

Comment: Do you think such autocomplete is useful? IMHO autocomplete should complete, but doesn't guess. If you don't remember the method name, you can press Ctrl + Shift + B (Go to sourse) and then Ctrl + Shift + F12 (Inspect members). There you can see all methods and search there using wildcards.

Comment: I think this is purely down to personal preference. The problem with the last suggestion is its 3 times the effort, you need to leave the context of the page you are working on on and I tend to lose my thought trail when this happens. This just gets a little frustrating when you have to keep doing it.  I wouldn't make it the default as it changes behaviour that users are used to, but would have it as a feature. Unfortunately when my memory isn't at it's best or APIs I'm less familiar with, it's just a useful additional tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For future reference, this is implemented since NetBeans 7.4 and can be enabled in the options:

1. In the menu bar click **Tools** -> **Options**
2. In the Options window open the **Editor** section and then click on the **Code Completion** tab
3. Tick the checkbox **Subword completion**

For Netbeans 8.0.2:

1. Under **Preferences**-> **Editor** tab -> **Code completion** tab
2. Change the Language drop down menu option from **All Languages** to **Java**
3. Tick the checkbox **Subword completion**

This is a really handy option :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can implement your own, if you have the stamina for it.

You have to implement a CompletionProvider Interface and according to Netbeans Docs: "As the user types in an editor, the code completion infrastructure asks all code completion providers registered in the XML layer file to create CompletionTasks."

Here's the link that might help you get there:
http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-code-completion.html